# Is using TempData["id"] safer than using hidden field for tracking an id between a round trip HttpGet and HttpPost?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

### Objective:

To prevent users from tampering any id (example: CustomerId, UserId, ProductId, etc) between a round trip (from invoking HttpGet-handling to HttpPost-handling action methods), I want to use `TempData[]`.

Most people,however, use hidden fields to keep track the ids. But I think users can still tamper them.

Shortly speaking,

1. Is using `TempData["id"]` safer than using hidden field for tracking an id between a round trip HttpGet and HttpPost?
2. Is there any disadvantage using `TempData[]`?

### Edit 1

In this scenario, I use `TempData[]` only for tracking ids, not for other fields.
The other fields are still exposed to the users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always validate user input and in this case make sure that whatever ID is passed in is actually the Id a user has access too.  So is if safer?  Not really because there is nothing flawed with hidden inputs if you do validation like you should anyway.

Using tempdata would mean you are accepting parameters from the routes ( presumably ) the HTML form and now TempData.  That seems awfully complex instead of having real security inside of your controllers.

TempData also goes away after every request made to it.  That means your Post methods will also have to populate TempData adding additional complexity.

Comment: The problem is figureing out if the ID is the same between requests.  You can't just do that with input validation.  Sure, you can make sure that the input is valid by format, and that the user has access, etc etc... but you can't really ensure that the id is the same between requests.

Comment: @CtrlDot - If userId = 3983 and your editing Car 382 then you'd check to make sure the user can load car where userId=3983 and Car=382 and then validate the save logic of that editing car.  This prevents any security issues. If the user wants to access 423 which is does not have permissions to the POST action will fail.  If the user decides to hack the hidden field to edit a car he already has permissions for well so be it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know TempData is stored in the session.  Technically this is more secure than hidden fields (almost anything is) unless your session data is persisted in cookies.  Then they are about the same.

If your session data is stored server side (say memory or database) then you are okay.

MVC 2 and higher, the TempData is only cleared when read.  So you should be good for that.

Comment: First, how to know whether or not `TempData` session is persisted in cookies? Second, `TempData` persisted in only one round trip still works for common tasks such as Edit, Create, Delete.

Comment: @Administrator  That is up to your IIS setup I believe.  Getting a little out of my realm, but sessions are usually a service provided by the web server.  I think by default IIS uses some sort of file based session.... but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'd expose the id in the URL and use permissions, validation, etc. to ensure that users are only accessing data (by id) that they really should be.  If you really need to track data (say, through a wizard or a shopping cart) that shouldn't be on the page, then I'd suggest simply using the session explicitly.